# How to generate a graph and determine its maximum spanning tree in Wolfram Mathematica?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, trees

I have just started learning Mathematica. I am trying to generate the following edge labeled graph $G$, and its maximum spanning tree using Wolfram Mathematica.
[image]

**Note.** A maximum spanning tree is a spanning tree of a weighted graph having maximum weight. Specifically, I have the following questions:

> (1) How to generate the graph $G$ in Wolfram Mathematica?

> (2) How to find the maximum spanning tree of $G$?

> (3) How to find the maximum spanning tree with terminal vertices $p$ and $v$?

Comment: At (1): https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html. At (2) and (3): https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSpanningTree.html

Answer (score 3):

For the input for your example, you can write `\[UndirectedEdge]`as `esc`ue`esc`. With this the input is:

[image: ![![enter image description here]

When you write it out, it is the unreadble mess:

```
Graph[{p \[UndirectedEdge] r, p \[UndirectedEdge] q, 
  p \[UndirectedEdge] t, r \[UndirectedEdge] q, q \[UndirectedEdge] s,
   r \[UndirectedEdge] s, s \[UndirectedEdge] t, 
  s \[UndirectedEdge] u, u \[UndirectedEdge] t, t \[UndirectedEdge] v,
   u \[UndirectedEdge] v}, 
 EdgeWeight -> {4, 3, 6, 5, 2, 7, 3, 3, 4, 7, 5}, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Now for the spanning tree, MMA has a function `FindSpanningTree`that calculates the minimum spanning tree. To get the maximum spanning tree, we simply take the negative of the weights:

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
FindSpanningTree[gr]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: @Szabolcs  You are right. Although it does not make a difference in this example, it could create problems in more complicated cases. Therefore, I changed it, thnak's.